# One-point compactification of a complex variety

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a scheme over $\operatorname{Spec}\mathbb{C}$, separated, of finite type. Does the one-point compactification of $X (\mathbb{C})$ have homotopy type of a finite CW-complex? If it's true, could someone give a reference for this fact?

Thank you.

Comment: Just to be sure, what topology are we using on $X(\Bbb C)$?

Comment: @Jesko Hüttenhain The analytic topology.